# Websocket not connecting in Karma

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am trying to create some karma tests and some of the functions I'm testing are supposed to make Websocket connections.

When running the code normally outside of Karma (using Chrome or Firefox), I see that my console log messages show that ws.onopen() fires as expected.

Not so when running in Karma using PhantomJS or even Chrome.  I'm running version 0.12 of Karma.  Could this be related to how Karma uses socket.io, instead of the browser's Websocket?

I am not doing anything in regards to manually writing a handshake.

```
webSocketConnect = function() {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.103.83:9000", "ws-xyz");

    ws.onopen = function(evt) {
        console.log("Connection is opened...");
    };
};
```

When webSocketConnect is invoked, i.e.:
webSocketConnect();
I get no error but I don't see "Connection is opened..." in the console log.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I think that the code is not getting executed because XSS protections are coming into play.  I took the code above and started playing around with it in jsfiddle and saw that when I ran it I would get: "
SecurityError: The operation is insecure."  I think it's a shame that Karma is not reporting any error.  In fact Karma is completely silent and I wasn't even noticing that none of the websocket code was being executed at all.

Comment: If you think it is such as same why not set logLevel: 'DEBUG' in your Karma configuration :)